# Delegated event handler does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a part of my HTML file;

```
<script type="text/template" id="_profile">
    <div class="modalDialog">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="box clearfix">
                <div class="box-header clearfix">
                    <span class="box-title l">{% trans 'PROFILE' %}</span>
                    <a href="#" style="margin-left: 10px;" id="profile_export" class="l"><span class="icon-download"></span>{% trans 'Profile Export' %}</a>
                    <div class="close-profile icon-cancel-circled r"></div>
                </div>
```

and

```
$('.profile').on('click', '#profile_export', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(root + '/profile/export/', function(resp) {
         // DO something
```

I have looked at some examples for "event delegation in jQuery" so I wrote above function. Probably it is wrong because when I click, it does not do anything. It just puts a `#` at the end of the current URL.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? Why when I click `#profile_export` does it not trigger the request to "profile/export/"?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of `.profile` as the primary selector is the problem. You need to hook the delegated event handler to an element which is in the DOM on page load. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#profile_export', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code...
});
```

Note that `document` here is just for the sake of an example. Ideally you should use the closest element available, in this case I would imagine it to be the element to which you're appending your `_profile` template.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point of delegating to a single element if that element isn't removed or added dynamically.

Unless that's the case you should go for:

```
$('#profile_export').on('click' function (e) {

});
```

Comment: `There's no point of delegating to a single element if that element isn't removed or added dynamically.` True, but given the OP has shown his code is generated from a template it obviously is appended dynamically and a static event handler isn't going to work here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Indeed my bad.